# How to update a csv file in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv

I am trying to insert values into a csv file but the file is not getting update on second iteration.  Can anyone suggest help?

```
for(var i =0;i <2;i++){
    var writer = csvWriter()
    writer.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('out.csv'))
    writer.write({name: data.name, email: data.email, gender: data.gender})
    writer.end()
}
```

Comment: What do you mean updated? By the look of things you're trying to create both files exactly the same (same data, filename) so it's unclear what do you expect.

Comment: Hi GillesC,i am trying to insert all my data one after the other but its getting overwritted.Pls see my updated code.

Answer (score 0):

When you use `fs.createWriteStream('out.csv')` you open the file for writing for the second time and overwrite it.

Also keep in mind that piping streams is asynchronous so even your first pipe will start doing anything only after all of the loop iteration have already finished.

You may want to read more about streams in Node.

Comment: Hi rsp,how can i update my csv instead of overwriting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
fs.appendFile()
```

You can get more informations on [Node documetation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_appendfile_file_data_options_callback).

Comment: It is throwing error,writter.appendFile() is not a function

Comment: Put the new declaration, pipe and close outside of the for iteration.